# Change the record type to it's previous value

Tags: page-layout, record-type

I have an object which has 6 or so `record types` with its associated `page layouts`. I have a field in each layout called 'Cancel' which is a checkbox. When the field is checked, the `record type` changes and another user has a field called 'Confirm Cancellation' which is a picklist value. If 'Yes' is selected, it goes to a different `record type` but if 'No' is selected, it should go back to it's previous `record type`.

The problem is the 'Cancel' field can be checked in any of the `record type`. So how do I go back to the previous `record type` if 'Confirm Cancellation' is 'No'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. In my `before update trigger` I captured the `RecordTypeId` in a field when I clicked on 'Cancel Demo'. Next in the same trigger, I updated the `RecordTypeId`with the field value when I selected 'No' in 'Confirm Cancellation'